# making different API calls

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I would like to make 2 Fetch API calls to transfer data from my JS file to my PHP file. The first call is conditional and transfer an array of data (that is properly treated in my PHP file)
The second API call is a sort of timer (using setInterval function) that I want to use to check if client is still on the browser (yes that is the final goal!).The 2 calls are working properly (don't get error and can get data correctly from the first array). The problem is that I don't know how to get the timer data separately in a variable in my PHP file (that I will next push it in array) ! Can you please show the way (I am still beginner with Fetch..)

Here is the code in my JS File

first Call

```
if(...Button pressed...){
    fetch("cart.php",{
        "method":"POST",
        "Headers":{
            "content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        "body":JSON.stringify(arrayOrderedProducts)
    })
    .then(function(response){
        return response.text()
    })
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    })
}
```

Second Call

```
setInterval(()=>{
    timer+=1
},1000)


function checkConnection(){
    fetch ("cart.php",{
        method:"Post",
        body :timer
    })
    .then(
        response=>{
        return response.text()})
    .then(
        response=>{
            console.log(timer)
    })
    .catch(
        error=>{
            console.log(error)
    })
}

let intervalConCheck = setInterval(()=>checkConnection(),1000)
```

Here is the code in my PHP file

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST)){
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $orders = json_decode($data);
    ...rest of code that retrieve data in arrayOrderedProducts...

}
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to modify your JavaScript code to send the timer value separately from the first call. Here's an example of how you can structure your JavaScript code:

```js
let arrayOrderedProducts = [...] // Your array of ordered products
let timer = 0; // Initialize timer

// First Call
if (... /* Button pressed condition */) {
    fetch("cart.php", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ orders: arrayOrderedProducts, timer: timer })
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

// Second Call (Timer)
setInterval(() => {
    timer += 1;

    // Update the timer value in the PHP file
    fetch("cart.php", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        },
        body: timer.toString()
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}, 1000);
```

In your PHP file, you can then handle the data received from both calls separately:

```php
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");

    // Check if the data is JSON (from the first call)
    $jsonData = json_decode($data, true);
    if ($jsonData !== null && isset($jsonData['orders'])) {
        $orders = $jsonData['orders'];
        // Process the $orders array here
        // ...

        // Example: Send a response back to the client
        echo "First call data processed successfully";
    }

    // Check if the data is plain text (from the second call)
    else {
        $timer = intval($data);
        // Process the $timer value here
        // ...

        // Example: Send a response back to the client
        echo "Second call data processed successfully";
    }
}
?>
```

This way, you can distinguish between the data sent in the first call (containing an array of ordered products) and the data sent in the second call (containing the timer value). Adjust the processing logic in your PHP file based on your specific requirements.

Comment: Dear Lucas thanks a lot for this neat code it works perfectly well :-) and welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy before posting further answers